# Use nginx to reverse proxy websocket AND add SSL to avoid mixed content?

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, wss

I have a service running that doesn't support HTTPS or WSS, and I unfortunately can't modify the service. As a workaround, I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy to add SSL for the HTTP connection, but the webapp is no longer working. Chrome dev tools give this error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://*****.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://******.com/service'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.`

Thus, the webpage itself loads, but the content does not.

Is there any way for nginx to run a reverse proxy on the websocket port as well?

Comment: Have you tried just changing `ws://` to `wss://` in your client-side code?